# Which algorithm should I use?

Tags: math, statistics, static-methods, static-analysis

I need to optimize the start time of scripts. I have:

- start time of each one script
- work time of each one script

I make graphic with matplotlib, it looks like this:

[image]

Each script should work out once a day
I need an algorithm, which may help me to optimize the start time of scripts

Comment: What I understand is that you want to minimize the sum of the start time. If so, then sort the scripts by start time (shortest first).

Comment: @MohamedAkram
No, I need to have a minimum number of scripts running in parallel at each time

Comment: The question is lacking key details that are needed to understand it. The minimum number of scripts running in parallel is obviously one -- just run the scripts sequentially. The quickest is achieved by starting all scripts in parallel at the same time, the time for that is the time of the longest script.  You need to clearly specify what measure you are trying to optimize and clearly state what the constraints are. Perhaps the constraint is that all scripts must start and finish within a 24 hour window?